# SQLite multiple SCAN TABLEs for a VIEW

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

My *EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN* says *that a table underlying a VIEW* is going to be scanned multiple times; is that really the case, and can I avoid it?

Here's a contrived example similar to my production data, which shows the issue with two made-up sports teams, in a world where we only trust people whose names begin with **D**, **E**, or **F**.

```
CREATE TABLE people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE trust (glob TEXT);
CREATE VIEW trusted_people AS
  SELECT * FROM people JOIN trust ON name GLOB glob;

CREATE TABLE teams (
  keeper INTEGER REFERENCES people(id),
  winger INTEGER REFERENCES people(id),
  scorer INTEGER REFERENCES people(id)
);

INSERT INTO people(name) VALUES ('alf'), ('bob'), ('chad'), ('don'), ('ed'), ('frank');
INSERT INTO trust(glob) VALUES ('d*'), ('e*'), ('f*');
INSERT INTO teams VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6);

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT tk.name, tw.name, ts.name FROM teams
  JOIN trusted_people AS tk ON teams.keeper = tk.id
  JOIN trusted_people AS tw ON teams.winger = tw.id
  JOIN trusted_people AS ts ON teams.scorer = ts.id
;

-- SCAN TABLE teams
-- SEARCH TABLE people USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
-- SEARCH TABLE people USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
-- SEARCH TABLE people USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
-- SCAN TABLE trust
-- SCAN TABLE trust
-- SCAN TABLE trust
```

Comment: You have no index on `people(name)`, and GLOB could use this index only if the pattern were known to be a prefix, which is not the case in a join. Can't you create a cache table with the IDs of trusted people?

Answer (score 0):

In general, in relational SQL a view will only perform as well as its underlying query.  In the case of the view `trusted_people`, using an index is not possible when joining to this view, since this is a derived table.  Hence, the join may not perorm so well.  To make matters worse, you are joining to this view three times.

But I see what I believe to be a problem in your database schema.  I think you can reduce your entire query to only two joins, by making the following change to the `teams` table:

```
team_id | player_id | role
1       | 1         | 'keeper'
1       | 2         | 'winger'
1       | 3         | 'scorer'
2       | 4         | 'keeper'
2       | 5         | 'winger'
2       | 6         | 'scorer'
```

Now the following query should yield the results you want:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM teams t1
INNER JOIN people p
    ON t1.player_id = p.id
INNER JOIN trust t2
    ON p.name GLOB t2.glob;
```

If you wanted a CSV list of each matching player per team, you could use this:

```
SELECT
    t1.team_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.name) AS players
FROM teams t1
INNER JOIN people p
    ON t1.player_id = p.id
INNER JOIN trust t2
    ON p.name GLOB t2.glob
GROUP BY
    t1.team_id;
```

Note than the second join between `people` and `trust` could still benefit from some index tuning, but just making this change alone might leave the performance at a level you can tolerate.